# Real-time updates in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I got the following JS code:

```
    function sumWithoutColor(range) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = sheet.getRange(range);
  var data = range.getValues();

  var sum = 0.0;

  for (var r in data) {
    for (var c in data[r]) {
      var x = parseInt(r, 10) + 1;
      var y = parseInt(c, 10) + 1;
      var cell = range.getCell(x, y);
      if (cell.getBackground() == '#ffffff') {
        sum += parseFloat(data[r][c]) || 0.0;
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

This code sums up only non-colored values in Google Spreadsheet:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWHA.png)

Green cell contains =sumWithoutColor("I3:I17"). As you can see, this function gets argument from cells.

When i add or delete data in white cells, or paint any cell, green cell does not updates, it contains previous value.

How do i make this cell to update when i add/delete/modify white cells?

Comment: Try putting `=now()` somewhere in the worksheet and reference that for absolutely no reason in the code. Maybe even a useless parameter. That should make the UDF volatile although I'm not sure if changing color is considered a volatile action in google-sheets; it isn't in Excel.

Comment: hello, Jeeped. thanks for you answer! putting =now() in the document could not work :(

Comment: Yeah, I tried to reference it within the code and use it as a parameter but it was  not allowed; probanly specifically because google-sheets does not want you to use volatile UDFs.